# How to split a json list in half in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON with a list of numbers from 1 to 10. How would I essentially split the list into half so that 1-5 gets saved into a new json, and 6-10 gets saved in another json?

```
var json = JSON.parse(body);
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried, a sample of the data you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take a look at some of these methods from [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array): splice, slice ;)

E.g.:

```
const middle = arr.length / 2; // if it's odd, it'll round down
const first = arr.slice(0, middle);
const last = arr.slice(middle, arr.length);
```